# Python: Can 1 function accept variables from 2 different fucntions

Tags: python

OK - I am trying to get a Python function to accept variables from two other functions.  Is this possible ?

A sample of what I am trying to do it below (I have simmed down the original code - for input here).  Hopefully you get theidea of what I am trying to do.  In a nutshell, I have Rectangle () which calls Extras() and the I want the output from Rectangle and Extras to be sent to the Calculate_Deposit ().

Is this possible ?

```
def calculate_deposit(total_cost, extras):
    deposit_percent = float(raw_input("Enter Deposit % (as a decimal) of Total Cost:    "))
    months_duration = float(raw_input("Enter the number of months client requires:    "))
    if deposit_percent >0:
        IN HERE JUST SOME CALCULATIONS
    else:
        print "The total amount required is:     ", total_cost

def rectangle(width, height, depth, thickness):
    type = raw_input("Enter lowercase c for concrete:  ")
    if type == 'c':
        output = IN HERE JUST COME CALCULATIONS
    else:
        return raw_input("Oops!, something went wrong")     
    print output + extras()
    total_cost = calculate_deposit(output, extras)                          

def extras():
    type = float(raw_input("Enter 1 for lights:  "))
    if type == 1:
        light = 200
        print "The cost of lights are:    ", light
        return light
    else:
        return raw_input("No extras entered")
```

Answer (score 2):

In `rectangle`, you call `extras()`, then you send just the function `extras` to `calculate_deposit()`. You want to send the result of the `extras()` call, not a reference to the function itself. You can make a minor change and save that value, referring to it when you print and when you go into `calculate_deposit`.

Change this:

```
print output + extras()
total_cost = calculate_deposit(output, extras)
```

To this:

```
extra = extras()
print output + extra
total_cost = calculate_deposit(output, extra)
```